# How to modify EngagementOverlayNotification.xaml or EngagementOverlayAnnouncement.xaml in Overlay folder under resources in windows universal app?

Tags: azure-mobile-engagement

with the help of Windows Universal Apps Reach SDK Integration

i have implemented POLL and Notification in my windows universal app, this is cool.

In the article they mentioned like

You can customize the overlay notification and announcement directly on their xaml and cs files:

```
EngagementAnnouncement.html : The Announcement web view html design.
EngagementOverlayAnnouncement.xaml : The Announcement xaml design.
EngagementOverlayAnnouncement.xaml.cs : The EngagementOverlayAnnouncement.xaml linked code.
EngagementNotification.html : The Notification web view html design.
EngagementOverlayNotification.xaml : The Notification xaml design.
EngagementOverlayNotification.xaml.cs : The EngagementOverlayNotification.xaml linked code.
EngagementPageOverlay.cs : The Overlay announcement and notification display code.
```

According to my needs, I want to customize the design in xaml file,  i have added a grid and customized it in EngagementOverlayNotification.xaml

but whenever i get the notification  the customized part is always visible in the app home screen? How to handle this issue?[Windows Universal Apps Reach SDK Integration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-engagement-windows-store-integrate-engagement-reach/)

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding an answer from [the MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89b6b19f-0cd5-4f62-8a8b-7b4d0911d806/how-to-modify-engagementoverlaynotificationxaml-or-engagementoverlayannouncementxaml-in-overlay?forum=azuremobileengagement):

> At that time, on the Windows Universal SDK, the XAML customization is limited to how the "WebView" xaml element is set for notification, announcement and polls within the grid. All other UI customizations have to be done on the HTML files from the Resources folder.